# How to create collection in Angular ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to create a collection or model in a project Angular Ionic (like Backbonejs).
Is it possible?
If yes, can I use Backbone?
If no, what can I do (the best way)?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Typically in Angular, you would just use straight up vanilla JavaScript objects.

```
var person = {
   firstName: "Andrew",
   lastName: "McGivery"
}
```

And a collection would just be an array of these objects...

```
var person1 = {
   firstName: "Andrew",
   lastName: "McGivery"
}

var person2 = {
   firstName: "Léon",
   lastName: "Jiresse"
}

var people = [person1,person2];
//or
people = [];
people.push(person1,person2);
```

In a way, the architecture of Angular kind of assumes you are getting your models from the backend (a server, webservice, etc) via $http.

```
app.factory("PeopleService",function(){
   return {
     GetPeople: function(){
        return $http.get('path/to/backend/people');
     }
   }
}

app.controller("PeopleController",function($scope,PeopleService){
    PeopleService.GetPeople().then(function(people){
        $scope.people = people;
    });
});
```

More Reading Material: http://www.wekeroad.com/2013/04/25/models-and-services-in-angular/